# Close solana program to get deployment funds back?

Tags: solana-program, deploy

I want to test my solana program on mainnet. I know that on devnet the deployment costs 5 SOL.

So I was wondering whether I could close the program account and get some of the deployment funds back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to close down a program. It probably has to be marked as `upgradeable` and only the `upgrade_authority` can close the program and recover the rent.

Answer (score 4):

If the program is upgradeable, you can do:

```
solana program close <PROGRAM_ID>
```

Which will give:

```
Closed Program Id <PROGRAM_ID>, 5.21619288 SOL reclaimed
```